# Why is it not possible to assign a string to a strongly typed boolean variable?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I try to assign a string to a strongly typed integer variable:

```
[int]$bar = '1'
```

This works, as PowerShell is able to cast the string `'1'` to an integer.

Now things are different if I attempt the same with a strongly typed boolean variable:

```
[boolean]$foo = 'foo'
Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 
or 0.
```

I find this confusing, as PowerShell at the same time allows an explicit cast from string to boolean:

```
[boolean]'foo'
True
```

Does anyone know the reason for this seemingly inconsistent behavior?

Comment: What happens if you try to do **$foo = 'foo'** and then **[boolean]$foo**?

Comment: The error message is perfectly valid as we know that bools can either be 1 or 0. Now, for the second snippet, it seems PS is returning a check on the length of the string. A cast on an empty string returns `false` otherwise its `true` whenever the string has length >= 1.

Comment: The reason is "such is the design". See also a similar issue [Switch-parameter-with-value](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/PowerShell.exe/Switch-parameter-with-value)

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll This works of course, as `[boolean]$foo` ist also an explicit cast.

Comment: @P.K. then the question about the second "seems" is where is this documented, and why it doesn't use the same conversion in both cases?

Comment: My guess would rather be that in **[boolean]$foo = 'foo'** the actual conversion is made by the assignment operator, and that operator don't use the ToBoolean/Parse, but an other function to cast it, that doesn't accept string. Anyone can prove/disprove it?

Comment: Also find this where conversion is tested using an if, might be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll I think that's exactly right. In 3.0 and above the idiomatic solution is to use an unchecked conversion: `$foo = "foo" -as [bool]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen do you have any "official" reference where this is documented?

Comment: the conversion/assignment failure or the `-as` keyword?

Comment: About what is the implementation behind the assignment operator and/or why it's different from casting.

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll No, it's an assumption based on observed behavior (ie. casting the variable during assignment fails, any other type of conversion succeeds)

Comment: There's note stating: "Because variables are created on assignment you have to assign a value to the strongly typed variable, if you do just [int]$new or you assign incorrect value [int]$new = “string” the strong typing won’t work, because the variable is not created." on the bottom of this page: http://powershell.cz/2012/12/01/explicit-type-casting-versus-strongly-typed-variables/ So it's indeed the assigment using a different conversion. But found nothing about what is the function exactly. Anyone else found smth about it?

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll I've added an answer with my best explanation of this behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Practical advice:

In most cases I would argue the following approach, rather than typed variables: Convert your **values** to the target type prior to assignment, and then let the type system infer the variable type:

```
$foo = [bool]"foo"
$foo = "foo" -as [bool]
$foo = $true -eq "foo"
```

---

### The problem at hand:

*(This is not an authoritative answer, but a best-guess)*

Briefly mentioned in the `about_Variables` help file:

> TYPES OF VARIABLES
>
> You can store any type of object in a variable, [...]
>
> Windows PowerShell variables are "loosely typed," which means that
>      they are not limited to a particular type of object. [...]
>
> [... section about value-inferred types bla bla bla ...]
>
> You can use **a type attribute** and cast notation to ensure that a
>      variable can contain only objects of the specified type or objects
>      that can be converted to that type. If you try to assign a value
>      of another type, Windows PowerShell tries to convert the value to
>      its type. If it cannot, the assignment statement fails.
>
> To use cast notation, enter a type name, enclosed in brackets, before
>      the variable name (on the left side of **the assignment statement**).

Although "type attribute" and the distinct constraint that this applies only during assignment is used nowhere else in the documentation, but (to me at least) indicates that this is a special case of explicit casting.

---

### What does this imply?

When you add an explicit cast notation to the *variable*, during assignment, as described above, PowerShell adds an `ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute` to the variable, and PowerShell's [type conversion magic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/06/11/understanding-powershell-s-type-conversion-magic.aspx) is suddenly overridden by a type-specific `Transform()` method:

```
PS C:\> $var = 5
PS C:\> Get-Variable var |fl *


Name        : var
Description :
Value       : 5
Visibility  : Public
Module      :
ModuleName  :
Options     : None
Attributes  : {}



PS C:\> [int]$var = 5
PS C:\> Get-Variable var |fl *


Name        : var
Description :
Value       : 5
Visibility  : Public
Module      :
ModuleName  :
Options     : None
Attributes  : {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}
```

If we repeat this experiment with a boolean type, you can see how the `ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute` transform is much more restrictive than the normal conversion "magic":

```
PS C:\> [bool]$foo = $true
PS C:\> (Get-Variable foo).Attributes[0].Transform($ExecutionContext,"foo")
Exception calling "Transform" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters
accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0."
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-Variable foo).Attributes[0].Transform($ExecutionContext,"foo")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
```

Again in this type of conversion **Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.**, whereas powershell itself generally interprets any non-empty, non-zero or non-null value to be `$true` when implicitly converted to `[bool]`.

*in other words*:

#### Cast notations are context-sensitive:

```
[bool]$SomeVariable = [bool]"bar"
   ^                ^   ^
   |                |   |
   |  during assignment |
This is a type attribute|
         This is a cast notation
```

Even though they look just the same

Comment: This is a good explanation on what happens, when the "wrong" type of value is assigned to a strongly typed variable. It is still curious that this leads to a different casting behavior compared to the "usual" type conversion magic. But this answers by question well enough.

Comment: I guess the "strongly typed" syntax reuses conversion rules from C#/.NET CTS to avoid having to re-implement [the rules that powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/06/11/understanding-powershell-s-type-conversion-magic.aspx) itself uses. This will also provide some consistency for developers coming from other .NET languages